# S8 rooted, Netflix is now incompatible

Tags: root-access, netflix

So I rooted my phone yesterday and now Netflix has been uninstalled. It says it's incompatible with my phone, please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Netflix does not allow being installed on a rooted device. If you manage to install it, it will refise to run (flash black and exit).

If you insist on installing it from Google Play, unroot your device first.

If you insist on letting it run well without unrooting your phone, consider using some Xposed modules (e.g. [RootCloak](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.devadvance.rootcloak2)).

Alternatively, you can unroot your phone then root it again with Magisk, as suggested by *Matthew Read*. However I haven't tested this method personally and I can't guarantee it'll be working.

References: 
[1](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/05/13/netflix-confirms-blocking-rootedunlocked-devices-app-still-working-now/),
[2](https://www.engadget.com/2017/05/14/netflix-no-longer-available-for-rooted-android-phones/),
[3](https://www.theverge.com/2017/5/15/15640820/netflix-blocks-app-rooted-android-devices),
[Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Netflix+root)

Answer (score 0):

Auto-uninstall shouldn't be possible; fresh installs can be prevented, and the app can block access, but I don't believe there is a (non-root) method for an app to remove itself.

That said, I run Netflix on my rooted device without issue.  You might be able to install it from elsewhere, such as from [APKMirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/netflix-inc/), and continue using it.

You could also flash your device back to stock and then use Magisk to root instead, which tricks the SafetyNet root detector thus Netflix will still run.  [This link](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/install-magisk-universal-systemless-interface-android/) has instructions.

Comment: @iBug I'm not sure how you can get "before" from "I rooted _and now_".  In any case, [Netflix runs perfectly on my rooted device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBiC4.jpg).